# Rails variable layouts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html, zurb-foundation

I'm using Rails 4 with the foundation 5 framework. Lets say I have the following index action:

```
class CompaniesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @companies = Company.all
  end
end
```

And I'd like to display the index in variable width containers like this:

```
<div class="first row">
  <div class="small-4 columns">
    <%= @companies[0] %>
  </div>
  <div class="small-8 columns">
    <%= @companies[1] %>
  </div>
</div

<div class="second row">
  <div class="small-8 columns">
    <%= @companies[2] %>
  </div>
  <div class="small-4 columns">
   <%= @companies[3] %>
  </div>
</div

<div class="third row">
  <div class="small-4 columns">
    <%= @companies[4] %>
  </div>
  <div class="small-4 columns">
   <%= @companies[5] %>
  </div>
  <div class="small-4 columns">
   <%= @companies[6] %>
  </div>
</div>

<%= Pagination %>
```

and so on.

How would you DRY this up and dynamically determine the width of the layout?

Comment: What is your algorithm or logic behind the different variable width?
Why has `@companies[0]` a `small-4 columns` and `@companies[1]` a `small-8 columns`?

Will every company after the fourth be displayed in a `thrid row` container?

Comment: Well, each row will be divided into 12 columns, and there will be 2 types of containers, 4 columns & 8 columns. Each row will have a different allocation of containers, but always up to maximum of 12 columns. For an idea of what I'm trying to achieve, here's a link https://medium.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, some things to consider:

---

**Object**

The first thing is you need to consider is that Rails is built using *objects* (not arrays). Your calling of `@companies[x]` is akin to calling an array. Whilst this is strictly the case, each member of the array is an **object**, and needs to be treated as such

The way to do this is to loop through the objects in the correct way:

```
@companies.each do |company|
   @company.name
end
```

I guess you were using the array in your question as a reference, but I figured I make it clear how Rails *should* work with objects

---

**Pattern**

There *has* to be a pattern with what you're asking. Juding by the comments, and your reference to `Medium.com`, I'd do something like this:

```
#app/views/your_view.html.erb
possibilities = [[4,8], [4,4,4], [8,4]]
@companies.each_slice(3) do |companies| 
   content_tag :div, class: "row" do
      format = possibilities.sample
      companies.each_with_index do |company, i|
         content_tag :div, class: "small-#{format[i]} columns" do
            = company.name
         end
      end
   end
end
```

This should create what you're looking for!
Although further testing is definition required

Comment: Your instincts are spot on as ever Rich. I'll try this out asap.

Comment: Haha maybe from a "guess" perspective - certainly needs some work. I remember doing something like this (without the random element) some time back. `each_slice` is a pure life saver!!!

Comment: btw speaking of medium.com, here's a post I made last month called "How To Create A Killer Brand" when I got to sit down with former Global Marketing Director for Harley Davidson & Aston Martin: https://medium.com/p/899b91b26dcf